# Converting JSON NString to NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

My json string is:

```
jsonData=@"{data:[{\"type\":\"ex\",\"coordinate\":\"19.0760,73.8777\",\"title\":\"Awesome Event 1\"},{\"type\":\"pe\",\"coordinate\":\"19.0760,73.2777\",\"title\":\"Awesome Event 2\"},{\"type\":\"ev\",\"coordinate\":\"19.0760,72.4777\",\"title\":\"Awesome Event 3\"},{\"type\":\"ex\",\"coordinate\":\"19.0760,72.3777\",\"title\":\"Awesome Event 4\"},{\"type\":\"pe\",\"coordinate\":\"19.0760,72.1777\",\"title\":\"Awesome Event 5\"},{\"type\":\"ev\",\"coordinate\":\"19.0760,72.4777\",\"title\":\"Awesome Event 6\"},{\"type\":\"ex\",\"coordinate\":\"19.0760,72.5777\",\"title\":\"Awesome Event 7\"},{\"type\":\"pe\",\"coordinate\":\"19.0760,72.9777\",\"title\":\"Awesome Event 8\"},{\"type\":\"ev\",\"coordinate\":\"19.1760,72.8777\",\"title\":\"Awesome Event 9\"},{\"type\":\"ex\",\"coordinate\":\"19.4760,72.8777\",\"title\":\"Awesome Event 10\"},{\"type\":\"pe\",\"coordinate\":\"19.5760,72.8777\",\"title\":\"Awesome Event 11\"},{\"type\":\"ev\",\"coordinate\":\"19.3760,72.8777\",\"title\":\"Awesome Event 12\"}]}";
```

How to convert it to NSDictionary?

Comment: `NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[jsonData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:&error]`? I'd rename `jsonData` into `jsonString`, because `Data` may think of `NSData` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all convert your jsonString into JsonData. As per your code the json is in string format. So follow the below steps.

-> Convert the jsonString to Data
-> Convert the data to JsonDict

**jsonString to Data**

```
NSData* data = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

After that

**Data to JsonDict**

```
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
```

Then you can access the values from the dict using Key names.

Comment: how to access the field "type" from "data"

Comment: You should get an warning at least with that code (and I'd guess a crash at run time), since `jsonData` is a `NSString` object, while the first parameter of `+ (id)JSONObjectWithData: options:error:` should be a `NSData` object.

Comment: how do you access diectly string to Dictionary, is this possible

Comment: yes it is possible.

Once you convert the data into a dict.

Access like this : `[jsonDict valueForKey:@"title"];`

Answer (score 0):

using NSJSONSerialization class and its method JSONObjectWithData you can convert string to dict or json.

```
NSData *data = [yourString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
//                              OR
id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
NSLog(@"string: %@",json);
```